# gcc assembler messages can't open /tmp/ccqjY5HV.s for reading no such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, centos, centos6, rhel, rhel6

I have a nightly build that builds a source tree with several compilers/options.  I'm using buildbot on centos 6, though I doubt that buildbot has any relation to the problem.

Sometimes the build fails with a bunch of messages like:

```
Assembler messages:
Error: can't open /tmp/ccqjY5HV.s for reading: No such file or directory
```

My first guess is that something is deleting these files behind the compiler's back.  I've looked at the tmpwatch cron job but the setup doesn't seem like a culprit.

The failures seem to happen around 10pm when several builds launch.  The actual compiles are locked so that only one compile happens at a time.

Any thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I found that adding [`-pipe`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) to my gcc command resolved these issues.

> -pipe
>
> Use pipes rather than temporary files for communication between the
>   various stages of compilation. This fails to work on some systems
>   where the assembler is unable to read from a pipe; but the GNU
>   assembler has no trouble.